# How do I get the longest list and the overall max value from a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, max

Given a list of lists, I would like to find the longest list, as well as the overall max value from all of the lists. Being restricted to not use `max()`, how can I go about doing this?

My attempt is shown below:

```
def newMax(table):
    a=-1
    if len(table) == 0:
        print("The list is empty")
    for i in range(len(table)*2):
        a+=1
        if i+1 >= len(table):
            print("Big number")
            break
        else:
            if len(table[a]) < len(table[a+1]):
                maxs=a+1
                if maxs < len(table[a+2]):
                    maxs = a + 2
                    print("test",table[maxs])
                    if maxs < len(table[a + 3]):
                        maxs = a + 3
                        print("test", table[maxs])

newMax([[1,3,1,5,1,51,15],[0,3,5,4,5],[1,2,3],[1,3,1,5]])
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by it doesn't work? What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: Can you describe more exactly what you need this to do? I see it takes in a list of lists. Do you want to fix the largest element in all the lists? Or the largest element in each list, or the longest list, or something else?

Comment: You just have a list of nested lists. You can iterate over the rows, and iterate over the values in each row. For each value, compare it to the largest value you've found so far.

Comment: I need to create a function that takes a list of type [[2,1,3], [0,], [2,5]], and make the return largest element in all the lists and largest element in each list. @CH

Comment: @Mozartlycee So for the example you gave you would get something like [3, 0, 5] and 5?

Comment: @CH. i get a error (IndexError: list index out of range).
in my head the result has to be, largest value in the list is 5 and the longest list is [2,1,3]

Comment: @Mozartlycee Wait, now I'm confused. Previously you mentioned you wanted the largest element in all the lists and the largest element in each list, but now you're saying the largest element in all the lists and the _longest_ list? Which of these do you need?

Comment: @CH. I'm sorry I wrote the answer too quickly.
I want the largest element in the list and the longest list.
excuse me again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find

1. the largest value in all the lists, and
2. the longest list,

simply iterate through all the lists while keeping track of the max encountered so far.

```
def newMax(table):

    maxValue = table[0][0]
    longestList = table[0]
    longestListLen = len(table[0])
```

This sets the largest value encountered so far to the first element of the first list, and sets the longest list to to be the first list. We then iterate through the rest of the lists to see if there are larger values / longer lists.

```
    for row in table: # iterate through all lists
        for val in row: # iterate through each value in each list
            if val > maxValue: # encountered a greater value
                maxValue = val # let's save the new biggest value

        rowLen = len(row) # get this list's length
        if len(row) > longestListLen: # encountered a longer list
            longestListLen = rowLen # save this list as the longest list
            longestList = row
```

Now you have the max value of all lists in `maxValue` and the longest list in `longestList`.

Comment: No problem. Please do go through each step of this solution to understand how it solves the problem.

Comment: I understood how the second part of your answer works but no the first part. can you explain me the first part please.

Comment: In the second part, we keep trying to find a value bigger than the largest value encountered so far. However, we need an initial value to start comparing to, which we set to be the first element.

Comment: Thank you.  one more question.  do you have books, videos ... to advise me to better learn python and to solve this type of problem?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot advise you further on that aspect. Learning basic programming concepts like this was so long ago to me (I have terrible memory) I couldn't even tell you what I used to learn.

Maybe you can check out [r/learnprogramming](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming) on Reddit. Their [wiki](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/wiki/books) does have some suggestions, though I do not personally have experience with them.

Answer (score 1):

Put all entries in a single collection, then take the max of that. This way, all the looping happens on the C-side, so efficient:

```
def newMax(table):
    s = set()
    for l in table:
        s.update(l)
    return max(s)
```

Based on the comments above and below, to get all the individual maxes and not use the builtin max(), while staying linear in time and not writing a super-nested function:

```
import heapq

def newMax(table):
    maxvalues = list()
    for l in table:
        heapq.heapify(l)
        maxvalues.append(heapq.nlargest(1, l)[0])
    mv2 = maxvalues[:]
    heapq.heapify(mv2)
    return heapq.nlargest(1, mv2)[0], maxvalues
```

One more as the goal/requirements seems to have changed again in the comments:

```
def newMax(table):
    length_max = -1
    max_length_list = None
    value_max = -2**31
    for l in table:
        if len(l) > length_max:
            length_max = len(l)
            max_length_list = l
        for i in l:
            if i > value_max:
                value_max = i
    return value_max, max_length_list
```

Comment: The question states "can't", not "not supposed to". I presumed the "can't" was b/c `max(table)` won't work.

Comment: Hm, good point actually. I was just assuming it's a homework question ("do this without using built-in methods")...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure have you learn recursion yet , which this is an recursion based solution, since I`m not sure how many level could have in your input list

```
input = [[1,3,1,5,1,51,15],[0,3,5,4,5],[1,2,3],[1,3,1,5]]

def findMaxRec(input):
    max = -999999999
    for i in input:
        if isinstance(i,list):
            temp = findMaxRec(i)
            if temp > max:
                max = temp
        else:
            if i > max:
                max = i
    return  max

print(findMaxRec(input))
```

Comment: This is nice in the sense that it does work for any dimension of lists of lists. However, setting `max = -999999999` runs into the danger of not working if all of the elements are less than -999999999, say if the input was `[[-9999999999999, -999999999998], [-9999999997]]`.

Comment: sorry I just put some random minus number

Comment: Perhaps consider setting the initial max to the very first element. Although for this solution you will have to recursively enter nested lists until you find the correct first element.